# Integrate $e^{2z}$ along the path $\cos(t)+it$ for $t∈[0,\pi/2]$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I need to calculate the integral

$$\int_{\gamma_1} e^{2z} \, \mathrm dz \quad \text{for} \quad \gamma_1(t) = \cos t + it,\; t \in [0,\pi/2],$$

but I don't think I can use Cauchy's Theorem or the Residue Theorem. And it's very complicated to calculate it directly. Is there any other method I can use to calculate this integral?

Answer (score 2):

We can form a closed contour by adding a portion of the real and imaginary axes to $\gamma_1$. Indeed, let \begin{align*}
\gamma_0(t) = t, &\quad t \in [0,1], \\
\gamma_1(t) = \cos t + it, &\quad t \in [0, \pi/2], \\
\gamma_2(t) = it, &\quad t \in [0, \pi/2].
\end{align*}
Then $\gamma = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 - \gamma_2$ is closed. Evaluating,
\begin{align*}
\int_{\gamma_0} e^{2z} \, \mathrm dz &= \int_0^1 e^{2t} \, \mathrm dt = \frac{e^2 - 1}{2}, \text{ and} \\
\int_{\gamma_2} e^{2z} \, \mathrm dz &= \int_0^{\pi/2} ie^{2it} \, \mathrm dt = -1.
\end{align*}
$e^{2z}$ is entire, so by Cauchy's theorem, \begin{align*}
0 &= \int_{\gamma} e^{2z} \, \mathrm dz = \int_{\gamma_0} e^{2z} \, \mathrm dz  + \int_{\gamma_1} e^{2z} \, \mathrm dz - \int_{\gamma_2} e^{2z} \, \mathrm dz \\
&= \frac{e^2}{2} - \frac 12 + \int_{\gamma_1} e^{2z} \, \mathrm dz + 1.
\end{align*}
Thus,
$$\int_{\gamma_1} e^{2z} \, \mathrm dz + 1 = - \frac{e^2 + 1}{2}.$$

---

*Edit*: Actually, the original integral is easy to evaluate.
Since $\mathrm d/\mathrm dt(2 \cos t + 2it) = 2(i - \sin t)$, \begin{align*}
\int_{\gamma_1} e^{2z} \, \mathrm dz &= \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{2 \cos t + 2it} (i - \sin t) \, \mathrm dt \\
&= \left[\frac 12 e^{2 \cos t + 2it}\right]_0^{\pi/2} \\
&= \frac 12 e^{0 + i\pi} - \frac 12 e^{2 + 0} \\
&= -\frac 12 - \frac{e^2}{2} = - \frac{e^2 + 1}{2}
\end{align*}